# Chrome extension: onStartup event is not working in Cognito window

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, service-worker, chrome-extension-manifest-v3

Chrome extension: onStartup event is not working in Cognito window

I am having below configuration in manifest.json

```
"incognito": "split",
```

And i am trying to execute the code logics inside **chrome.runtime.onStartup** event in service worker (MV3) but it is not working. Startup event is not triggered in the incognito mode but it is working in normal mode. In both chrome and chromium edge browsers.

```
chrome.runtime.onStartup.addListener( ()=> {
   // Code logics here
} );
```

If I moved those code logics in the top of the service worker file then it is working, but I want to handle it inside onStartup event only. Also, 'incognito' should be in 'split' mode in manifest.json

Would be grateful if i get any help from anyone.

Thanks in advance!!

Answer (score 0):

Looks like a bug in Chrome.

One workaround would be to use chrome.extension.inIncognitoContext:

```js
if (chrome.extension.inIncognitoContext) {
  chrome.storage.session.get('onStartup', r => {
    if (!r.onStartup) {
      chrome.storage.session.set({onStartup: true});
      console.log('Initializing in incognito...');
      // ...............
    }
  })
}
```

And add `"permissions": ["storage"]` to manifest.json.